# Access Pixels in GrayScale Image

Tags: c#

How can I access individual pixel values in a GrayScale Bitmap that is formatted with `Format16bppGrayScale`? When I use the `GetPixel()` method, I get a `System.ArgumentException` in `System.Drawing.dll`.

**Edit:**

The following method creates a Grayscale Bitmap `bmp`. How can I see its content (pixel values)?

```
    // This method converts a 2dim-Array of Ints to a Bitmap
    public static Bitmap convertToImage(int[,] array)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (int* intPtr = &array[0, 0])
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(5, 7, 4, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, new IntPtr(intPtr));
            }
        }

        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(), bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
        IntPtr bmpPtr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Here, I would like to see the pixel values of "bmp", which should be similar to the values in "array"

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a small example code snippet that reproduces this and the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [LockBits method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) of Bitmap to lock the bits and retrieve an IntPtr to the memory pointer containing the pixel info. From there you can use indexing to get to the bytes that interest you. You can see the example on MSDN for more information.

**UPDATE**

Taking from your example, then replace your code with this:

```
// This method converts a 2dim-Array of Ints to a Bitmap
public static Bitmap convertToImage(int[,] array)
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* intPtr = &array[0, 0])
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(5, 7, 4, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, new IntPtr(intPtr));
        }
    }

    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(), bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
    IntPtr bmpPtr = bmpData.Scan0;

    byte[] dataAsBytes = new byte[bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, dataAsBytes, 0, dataAsBytes.Length);

    // Here dataAsBytes contains the pixel data of bmp

    return bmp;
}
```

You can use the bmpData.Stride / bmp.Width to find the size of bytes that each pixel takes to be easier to naviget the array.

**Update #2**:

To find the first byte data of the pixel with indexOfPixel you can do:

```
byte firstByteOfPixel = indexOfPixel * bmpData.Stride / bmp.Width;
byte secondByteOfPixel = 1 + (indexOfPixel * bmpData.Stride / bmp.Width);
```

You can compare that to your multidimensional array.

Comment: I added an example, where I have an IntPtr `bmpPtr`. How can I view the content of my GrayScale Image? I would like to reverse the conversion from `int[,]` to `Bitmap`, i.e. I want to convert back from `Bitmap` to `int[,]`.

Comment: Hello @Boozzz, let me update my answer to include an example. I will need a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Boozzz, I have updated my answer based on your new comments. If this solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: When I call `convertToImage(new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } })` the input `array` is not equal to `dataAsBytes`. `dataAsBytes` includes lots of zeros. I guess that is because 'Marshal.Copy' expects a one-dimensional bitmap, but mine is two-dimensional.

Comment: @Boozzz dataAsBytes IS a one dimensional array of bytes containing the pixel info. As I mentioned, each pixel has a width of bmpData.Stride / bmp.Width bytes so you can use simple indexing, please see my revised answer. You can use that to set your data in any way you see fit. You asked how to access the pixels of a grayscale bitmap and I answered. Please ask another question if you have another problem.

Comment: Yes, and thank you for answering! However, `dataAsBytes` does not include ALL the pixels. Most of them have zero values.

Comment: @Boozzz dataAsBytes does include ALL bytes DEFINITELY. The above method definitely copies ALL bytes of all pixels to dataAsBytes. You can verify that through the public C# reference code. The reason some may be zero is if the values of the pixels they represent are close to black. For example, if a pixel is closer to black than to white, the first byte of the pixel should be zero. Also if the pixel is black, then both will be zero. Also check the way you create the bitmap; this code above is sure to work correctly.

Comment: You're right! The way I created my bitmap was wrong. Solution: `array` has to be of `byte[,]`.